# How to increase baudrate on Device Manager Windows?

Tags: windows, serial-port, fpga, uart, com-port

When I open device manager>com port> port settings,

I see max available baudrate option is 921_600 (not 115k). How can i increase this value? Because i know my fpga board(basys3) supports much faster than this.
[com_port view] here is an example image:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N78hF.png)
Btw, is it necessary to configure this device manager section for UART?

I've always configured this section before using serial port.

Comment: It's likely the com port on your PC doesn't go any higher than this.  USB was invented for a reason.

Comment: @MarkRansom Wdym? I'm using an USB cable to connect my Basys3 board to computer. Basys3 board is using USB cable for serial communication too.

Comment: I mean that USB is capable of much higher data rates than a serial port.

Comment: That is not a real serial port, it is emulated by the USB driver to make it simple to talk to the device.  Actual data transfer happens on the USB bus, through the USB cable you used to connect your PC to the trainer board, using pure USB protocols and signaling rates.